# Subir app grande 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

Tengo una aplicacion de casi 18.000 archivos, es una aplicacion grande desarrollada en laravel. como puedo subirla a 00webhost para probarla antes de comprar un hosting premium. Tendria que subir la aplicacion por archivo soltar y arrastrar o lo puede subir con un repositorio en git?

Comment: deberias usar un archivo comprimido ZIP o RAR no se cual soporte

Comment: y desde hay conectar por FTP para subir cambios puntuales de archivo puntuales

Comment: no creo que ese hosting gratuito te soporte esa cantidad de archivo spero bueno